# How to preserve the item order in a Python dictionary?

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary

I am writing a script in which the computer will play a game of war with itself. I need the script to only return the value of the first entry in the list:

Note: This is only an example

```
    test = {'hey':1, 'hi':2, 'hello':3, 'greetings':4, 'goodmorning':5,   'night':6}

    for a in test:
        print test[a]

    #this returns
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
```

I would like this script to only return the value of the first entry.

Comment: Dictionaries are not ordered collections in the sense that you don't access the *values* by position (i.e. 1st, 2nd, etc); you access them by keys (e.g. `test['hey']`, `test['hi']`, etc.)

Comment: did you try: `print a` as well?

Comment: Do you mean to return [1] as per your example ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python dictionary, keep keys/values in same order as declared](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867861/python-dictionary-keep-keys-values-in-same-order-as-declared)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since dictionaries are unordered, and if you are dependent on using a dictionary, but order matters to you, you should consider using an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) from collections. This will preserve the order of your dictionary based on insertion. So, if you enter `a, v, b`, it will be in that order.

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d = OrderedDict()
>>> d['a'] = 1
>>> d['v'] = 1
>>> d['b'] = 1
>>> d
OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('v', 1), ('b', 1)])
```

To get the first value based on requirements to get only the first entry:

```
d.items()[0][1]
```

Comment: yes, but I need for the only thing to be returned to be the value of the entry. In this particular case, the value is 1.

Comment: @Mezex Yes...look at my answer...the last line of my example gets you that.

Comment: @Mezex -You can simply append it to list like :     list1.append(dict_name.values()[0])

Comment: @Mezex: try `d.items()[0][1]` for getting the first tuple in the dictionary and then the *value* instead of the *key*.

Comment: That's a good point @ray . Easier to follow. I can update my answer with that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The built-in Dictionaries are not ordered collections in the sense that you don't access the *values* by indexed positions (i.e. 1st, 2nd, etc).

Instead, you access them by *keys* (e.g. `test['hey']`, `test['hi']`, etc.). For example:

```
>>> test = { 'hey':1, 'hi':2, 'hello':3 }
>>> test[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 0
>>> test['hi']
2
```

You should look at the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) on using dictionaries.

If you want to access elements by *position* (i.e. an index), then you should consider using a list or a tuple instead.

You might want to look at the `OrderedDict` class [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead if you wish to preserve order while still using a dictionary.

Quoting from the docs:

> An OrderedDict is a dict that remembers the order that keys
>   were first inserted. If a new entry overwrites an existing entry, the
>   original insertion position is left unchanged. Deleting an entry and
>   reinserting it will move it to the end.

See [idjaw's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33444597/4594973) for a good example on using the `OrderedDict`.